# How to execute a Unix shell script via GWT?

Tags: shell, unix, gwt, runtime, exec

Im building an GUI that will help my team mates to execute some jars without going using the terminal (with all the validating and stuff).

At some stage, the gui sould gather params from the gui and execute them, something like : `--start -Xbootclasspath/p:lib/OB-4.3.4.jar:lib/OBNaming-4.3.4.jar -Dmy.property.ns=corbaloc:iiop:localhost:900/NameService -Dmachine=energie -Dexecutable=MOREventd  -DtypeArbo=1 -jar MOREventd`

I was wondering how could i do that since Runtime Exec doesn't work with Google Web Toolkit)

thx for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GWT module will need to send details about the invocation to a server by using [GWT-RPC](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html), [RequestFactory](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html), or some other communication package.  The server will then execute the commands on behalf of the browser client.

Comment: Got it.
Now, which is the easiest to implement ? it's for like a simple program. Do you have some basic tutorials ?