# How to call a bash script from GWT-RPC server (Java)

Tags: java, bash, gwt, gwt-rpc, processbuilder

**I want to call a bash script from GWT server**

I coded up my first application with GWT/RPC, and I need to call a bash script on the server side (from MyOwnServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements MyOwnService).

**ProcessBuilder doesn't work**

To do that, I confess that I am using java.lang.ProcessBuilder, which is apparently "not supported by GAE" (I just ignored the warning). As it is running on the server side, it seemed to me that it should work anyways. I feel that I am missing something.

*Something seems to be preventing the call from being executed*, even though the required packages are correctly imported, the binaries are found, the execution doesn't crash. But the call is just not successful (for example even mkdir is not executed on the server).

**Related posts weren't much help...**

[How to execute a Unix shell script via GWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693623/how-to-execute-a-unix-shell-script-via-gwt?answertab=active#tab-top) (does not give a complete answer, and I could not simply comment on the answer)
[GWT + ProcessBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413722/gwt-processbuilder) (mentions precisely the solution I implemented which is not working for me, see above)

Any thoughts on this would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a GWT application **without GAE** you can use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("some command");`
If you want to read out the result of the command, you can use:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("A command");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
 while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
     builder.append(line + "\n");
 } 
String result = builder.toString();
```

If the command above should  not work, i guess you have to remove GAE from your project to run a bash script.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So you are saying that the problem is GAE. Now comes the noob question, how do I remove it from my project?

Comment: You could create a new project and uncheck the "Use Google App Engine" checkbox. Then you have to transfer your code to the new project, then the code above should work.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can call bash script with GWT,if your servet side on your computer.
2. the limit is GAE for secury. no way to cross this limit.

Comment: Thanks. About (1) I also think I can, but it doesn't seem to work, that is my problem.

Comment: your local env also GAE? please try tomcat or other java container.

Comment: I see. It's GAE indeed. So this might be the problem. Now is there a way I can easily switch to Tomcat?